# meta_search order by count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have these models and I'm playing with meta_search to order it.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :delivers
  has_many :estimates, :through => :deliver
end

class Estimate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :delivers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :companies, :through => :delivers
end

class Deliver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :estimate
  belongs_to :company
end
```

As you can see a company has many estimates and I need a filter to show companies in this order: from company who has the highest number of estimates to company that has the lowest number of estimates.
I'd like to have a sort link for it, something like:

```
= sort_link @search, :estimates_asc
```

I know that I can order in that way companies with this statement

```
Company.joins(:estimates).sort_by{|x| -x.estimates.size}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Here is a great Railscast on this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

This is my case and try it in your project, I'll help you with what I can:

So I have cars table with carname_id and carmodel_id in it. then 2 more tables for carnames and carmodels both with name and id in it. now let's say I have carname Mercedes with id 2 and carmodel S classe with id 5, in this case my cartable will contain values 2 and 5 Mercedes S classe.

To sort them by fields I did this way:

in cars **controller:**

```
  @search = Car.search(params[:search])
    @search.meta_sort ||= 'created_at.desc'  <-- this line is for default order display, you can use any other field
    @cars = @search.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
```

and in **view**

```
<%= sort_link @search, :carname_name,  "Car make" %>  <-- carname is the field from 

    car table where the carname id is stored and name is the he name itself for this id that's in carname table

<%= sort_link @search, :carmodel_name, "Car model"%>
```

that's all good now.

in your case I just assume it will be something like

<%= sort_link @search, :company_estimate,  "Car make" %>

hope it helps.